# Is it possible to specify extern in an inline function?

Tags: d

I have a function type `alias Func = extern (C) void function();` and a function that receives Func as parameter `extern (C) void whatever(Func);`. Is it possible to create an inline function with the extern (C) linkage when invoking `whatever`?

For example:

```
Func x = function() {}
whatever(x); //Works
whatever(function() {}); // Compilation error, invalid linkage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... but only if `Func` takes a parameter and you define the inline function with*out* specifying the type of that parameter.

```
extern(C) alias Func = void function(int);

extern(C)
void foo(Func f) {

}

void main() {
        Func x = function(a) {};
        pragma(msg, typeof(x));
        foo(x);

        foo(function(a) {});
}
```

That works. Nothing else I've tried does and looking at the grammar at dlang.org, it doesn't say it allows the `extern` word on an inline function, so I don't think I'm missing anything (though it is always possible that I am).

The reason the argument one works is because when you don't specify an argument type in a function literal, the compiler makes it a *template* literal, automatically instantiated with the type the receiving function expects when you pass it.

Since the receiving function expects `extern(C)`, the template gets that for free too.

Note that I haven't tried *running* this, maybe it compiles but does the wrong thing at runtime.

However, I don't believe there's any similar trick for zero-argument inline functions.

---

You can probably also get away with writing a global level template that wraps your given function and returns that. Behold:

```
extern(C) alias Func = void function();

extern(C)
void foo(Func f) {

}

template wrap(alias f) {
    extern(C) void wrapped() {
        // you can also put stuff like try/catch
        // in here if you like so exceptions don't
        // accidentally pass through the C function
        return f();
    }
    Func wrap() {
        return &wrapped;
    }
}

void main() {
        Func x = function() {};
        pragma(msg, typeof(x));
        foo(x);

        foo(wrap!(function() {}));
}
```

The wrapper solution has pros and cons too, like being able to add the try/catch or use on ordinary D functions, but the con is you need to actually use the wrapper and write it (though you could automate the writing of the wrapper using the std.traits stuff).

Comment: I tested the template literal function solution (function literal without arguments' types) and it worked, no runtime error.